# Zero extending a part of register

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm debugging the following function:

```
_print_func:
    mov rdx, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, str
    movzx dx, byte [str_len] ; <--- Here
    syscall
    ret
```

The function was compiled with

```
nasm -g -f elf64 2.asm
```

The issue I faced with is that after stepping the line `movzx dx, byte [str_len]` the rdx content was:

```
rdx            0xffffffffffff000d       -65523
```

And it was reasonable. Now, replacing the instruction as this:

```
_print_func:
    mov rdx, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, str
    movzx edx, byte [str_len] ; dx replaced with edx
    syscall
    ret
```

Now the register content is this:

```
rdx            0xd      13
```

It looks like moving to 32-bit register zero extending it's 64 bit high part. Why is that happening?

Why did not we zero extend `eax` when `movzx dx, byte [str_len]`?

Comment: Writing to a 32bit GPR zeroes the upper half of the corresponding 64bit GPR

Comment: @harold Very interesting. I noticed that in the debugger. But what was the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to a 16 bit register, only these 16 bits of the corresponding 64 bit register are changed.  However, when you write to a 32 bit register, the other 32 bit of the corresponding 64 bit register are cleared.  That's one of the quirks introduced in long mode (64 bit mode).